# Attempted relative import beyond top-level package in django

Tags: python, django

Trying to build a Django app with a signup app within the main app itself

I receive this error message:

```
from ..signup import views as signup_views
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

This is the structure of my app

```
 ---PeerProgrammingPlatform
 ------peerprogrammingplat
 --------->peerprogrammingplat
 --------->signup
```

This is my views (in signup):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create your views here.
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned.data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup/register.html', {'form':form})
```

my urls.py (peerprogrammingplat):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from ..signup import views as signup_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', signup_views.register, name="register"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be imported only with the name of app:

```
from signup import views as signup_views
```

It's because it looks from `manage.py` level.

Comment: I get the error message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'peerprogrammingplat.signup'

Comment: Have you tried without the `.`? Just `from signup import views as signup_views`.